# Name nested regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match strings of the form:

`"FLOAT:FLOAT:FLOAT"`

where:
`FLOAT="(\d*\.\d*)"`

I would like to not repeat code. (eg. `"(\d*\.\d*):(\d*\.\d*):(\d*\.\d*)"`)

Is there support for this in regex? Or is this typically done with string manipulation (.format())?

I'm using python, but I'm interested in other flavors of regex as well.

Comment: `(\d+\.\d+:){3}`

Comment: @jordanm doesn't match the original string (trailing ':').The linked questions answered it though